# How to add styles in existing function?

Tags: functions, css

The goal is to add some internal styles to a function. The function has some if statements, and then it does:

```
$content .= "
<div>
   <h3>stuff</h3>
   <div>$additional_stuff</div>
</div>";

endwhile;
```

I'd like to put some styles

in there, too, so it loads when the h3 and additional_stuff loads, but my attempts ways just break it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's couple of examples on how to add styling to your code.

```
// Method 1. define classes in another variable, then do styling in styles.css
$classes = 'another-class';

$content .= "
<div id=\"my-id\"class=\"my-class\"> // Method 2. use backslashes to escape double quotes and add id and classes as needed, then do styling in styles.css
   <h3 class=\"{$classes}\">stuff</h3> // Method 1. interpolate classes where needed
   <div style=\"background-color: blue; color: #fff;\">{$additional_stuff}</div> // Method 3. use backslashes to escape double quotes and add inline styles
</div>";
```

p.s. do remove the comments from the example code before copy-pasting `$content` to production.